# Transformin Square into Circle using jQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am working on an assignment and it seems like everything is working except in Task Two, step 5.Increase the border radius to 30px over 1.5 seconds
This change is supposed to transform the shape into a circle, but as you can see it is far from a circle. I noticed changing the radius to 150px~ gives you a circle. But my prof said 30px, any ideas if it's a mistake on my end or his?

Thanks!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project 19</title>
  <style>
    html {margin:2em; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
    h1 {margin:0;}
    h2 {color:#369;}
    hr {margin:2em 0;}
    .box {width:100px; height:100px; padding:2em; border:1px solid black; background-color:#069;}
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <h2>Task One</h2>
  <p>Add the jQuery to accomplish the following effects in tandem when the box is clicked:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Increase the width and height to 200px each</li>
    <li>Increase the font size to 44px</li>
    <li>Increase the border width to 10px</li>
    <li>Animation should take a total of 1.5 seconds</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="box box1" id="b1">I am a box.</div>

  <script>
  $('#b1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({
      width: '200px',
      height: '200px',
      fontSize: "44px",
      'border-width':'10px'
    }, 1500);
  });
  </script>

  <hr>

  <h2>Task Two</h2>
  <p>Add the jQuery to accomplish the following effects **in sequence** when the box is clicked:</p>
  <ol>
    <li>Increase the width to 120px over half a second</li>
    <li>Increase the height to 120px over half a second</li>
    <li>Wait for 1 second</li>
    <li>Increase the font size to 44px over 1 second</li>
    <li>Increase the border radius to 30px over 1.5 seconds</li>
    <li>When animation #4 is <b>complete</b>, change the text to "I am a circle."</li>
  </ol>
  <div class="box box2" id="b2">I am a box.</div>

  <script>
  $('#b2').on('click', function(){
    $(this)
      .animate({width: '120px'}, 500)
      .animate({height: '120px'}, 500)
      .delay(1000)
      .animate({fontSize:'44px'}, 1000, function(){ $('#b2').text('I am a circle.')})
      .animate({borderRadius: '30px'}, 1500)
  ;
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `border-radius` along with [**CSS3 Transitions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('#target').addClass('circle');
});
```

```css
#target {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;width:100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
  transition: border-radius 0.8s ease
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>

<button>Transform!</button>
```

I tend to avoid using jQuery when tasks like these can be achieved using CSS3 Transitions. They are supported by most browsers but if you wish to use jQuery `.animate()`, you can use the other example

---

Your professor may of said `30px` but that depends on the *width* / *height* of the element. Use `50%` to produce a circle every time.

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('#target').animate({
    "border-radius": "50%"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#target {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border-radius: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
<button>Transform</button>
```